What does the [1: ] in K.int_shape(x)[1:] mean?
In the code below the shape before flattening the array is needed in order to enter into the decoding part of an autoencoder. Isn't pre_flattened_shape = K.int_shape(x) enough to get the shape of the array before flattening? Why do we need the [1:] part at the end? I am not sure what [1:] means. The documentation for int_shape does not explain it. I know the shape before flattening is (None, 4, 4, 150).
#THE ENCODER CODE
encoder_input = layers.Input(
shape=(32, 32, 1), name = "encoder_input"
)
x = layers.Conv2D(10, (4, 4), strides = 2, activation = 'relu', padding="same")(
encoder_input
)
x = layers.Conv2D(50, (4, 4), strides = 2, activation = 'relu', padding="same")(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(150, (4, 4), strides = 2, activation = 'relu', padding="same")(x)
**pre_flattened_shape = K.int_shape(x)[1:]**

x = layers.Flatten()(x)
encoder_output = layers.Dense(4, name="encoder_output")(x)
encoder = models.Model(encoder_input, encoder_output)


SOurce code of int_shape. Returns a tuple so [1:] is a slice of it

[1:] means all elements except the first (which is at index 0).

Why would they leave aout the first element? Is it because the first element represents the number of batches?
